# prawn - import image from URL

Tags: ruby, image, relative-path, prawn

I can't seem to figure out how to import an image from an url

To import the images from my localhost I use:

```
image"./assets/images/img.png"
```

When I replace the path with an URL it says

```
`image' : URL not found
```

Is there a solution for this, or should I create a def that downloads the image and to use the path it returns?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

you need to do the following -

```
require "open-uri"

Prawn::Document.generate(INSERT_YOUR_PDF_FILENAME_HERE) do 
   image open(INSERT_YOUR_URL_HERE)
end
```

Refer to http://rubydoc.info/gems/prawn/0.12.0/frames for more details.

Comment: Thx, but I found that same solution later that day :-). I forgot to post it here. Thank you anyway! If I would not have found it on my own, this would have fixed the problem for me!

Comment: Good that your problem has been resolved and I think it would be nice if you accept or uptick this answer!

Comment: How can I use this if I have a file.pdf.rb because i think that code is for the controller ??

Comment: Could someone tell me how to use this in https://github.com/spree-contrib/spree_print_invoice/blob/master/app/views/spree/admin/orders/invoice.pdf.prawn  on line 8? I cant seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

I got this working for me:

```
image open("https://driver.mbpgroup.eu/images/mbp_logo.jpg"), position: :right, width: 250
```

I could NOT get this to work for me (Prawn documentation):

```
image "https://driver.mbpgroup.eu/images/mbp_logo.jpg", position: :right, width: 250
```